# Javascript : Check if any of the element in array is null or empty (Return True-False)

Tags: javascript

I have below array in javascript -

```
[
{
 id:1,
 deptName:"Cashier"
},
{
 id:2,
 deptName:"MF"
},
{
 id:3,
 deptName:""
},
{
 id:4,
 deptName:"RD"
},
{
 id:5,
 deptName:null
},
]
```

I want to check if any element for deptName in above array is null or empty.

I used -

```
var isNullOrEmpty= data.every(ele=>(ele.deptName===null || ele.deptName===""))
```

use of `every` function is returning false in every case. i.e. whether I keep deptName in any  of the element to be null / empty or I fill it with value. With both the cases it is returning me false.

I want to check if any of the deptName in array is null or empty.

Comment: As the name suggests. [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) returns `true` when _every_ element in the array fulfills the test. You want [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery or React. So why the tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**every()** method in JavaScript is used to checks whether all the elements of the array satisfy the given condition or not. The Array. **some()** method in JavaScript is used to check whether at least one of the elements of the array satisfies the given condition or not.
For your issue:

```
var isNullOrEmpty= data.some(ele=>(ele.deptName===null || ele.deptName===""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use array.map function with an if to check if the value not exist or empty:

```
arr.map((item, index) => {
 if (!item?.deptName) {
     console.log(`array index =>[${index}] is null or empty.`);
    }
 });
```